# VB/ASP.Net: Change static String to own class - how?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, object, shared

I used to have a Public class with around 1800 Public Shared Strings in it - kinda like my constants library:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly NLS_ALREADY_IN_USE_QUERYNAME As String = "AlreadyInUseQueryName"
```

Now I want to store a little more info for each element and change them to "As MyClass" with an appropriate constructor that takes the String from my previously used definition:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly NLS_ALREADY_IN_USE_QUERYNAME As QNLSDefinition = New QNLSDefinition("AlreadyInUseQueryName", "Deutsch", "English")
```

The problem is that these "objects" are not instantiated automatically although they are Shared. String obviously is "immediately instantiated".

Any best practise around for this?

Comment: Could you paste an small example?

Comment: Hi Carlos, I have updated the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Constructor for that Class and you instantiate all Static variables there in your contructor just one time in your application:

```
Class Constants 

   Public Shared ReadOnly NLS_ALREADY_IN_USE_QUERYNAME As QNLSDefinition

   'Constructor
   Sub New()

      NLS_ALREADY_IN_USE_QUERYNAME = New QNLSDefinition("AlreadyInUseQueryName",  "Deutsch", "English")

   End Sub

End Class
```

And then you go to your application constructor

```
Sub New()
   InitializeComponent()
   'Instantiate shared variables
   Dim const as new Constants
 End Sub()
```

Comment: Nice, will I be able to access NLS_XXX without using const. before it?

Comment: Import your class at the beginning of the program and no need to use const :D. Imports Constants

Comment: Muchos Gracias Carlos! :-) Would you put the Dim inside Application_Start or Session_Start in an ASP.Net app?

Comment: Application_Start is ok. So you have available that values in all the application scope.

Comment: Amazing Carlos. Will this be a big performance breaker - using objects instead of Strings? The object is very simple: 1 String and a List Of NameValue (2 string object).